# Detecting the end of a multiline regex sample (equivalent of \z)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to match each section of a string starting with one or more `+` and ending whenever it finds another instance of it or the end of the sample.

The sample is the following:

```
+ Horizontal Rules

Lorem ipsum

+ Lists

Everything about lists

++ Bulleted Lists

Make a list element by starting a line with an asterisk. To increase the indent put extra spaces
before the asterisk.

+ Another title

content
```

The regex I'm currently using (`/^(\++) (.*?)(?=^\++)/gms`) will split the sample into different matches. But in this case, the last section isn't matched, since the look-ahead doesn't find anything:

```
+ Another title

content
```

I tried using `\z`, which is supposed to match the end of the sample in a multiline regex :

```
^(\++) (.*?)(?=^\++|\z)
```

But unfortunately, the JavaScript regex engines haven't implemented this basic feature, making it look for a literal `z` instead.

Is there any way to replicate `\z` behavior ?

I've tried the following regex without any concrete results : `^(\+)+ (.*?)(?=^\++)|(?:$(?!.*))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(\++) (.*?)(?=^\+|$(?!.))/gms
```

The `$(?!.)` part matches the end of a line that is not followed with any char (`.` with `s` modifier matches any char).

However, it is more efficient to unroll the lazy dot matching part to grab whole lines that do not start with `+`:

```
/^(\++) (.*(?:\r?\n(?!\+).*)*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/er1Rld/1/). Note the absense of the `s` flag.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `(\++)` - Capturing group 1: one or more `+` symbols
- - a space
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\+).*)*)` - Capturing group 2:

  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\+).*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\r?\n(?!\+)` - a CRLF or LF line ending that is not immediately followed with `+` (if you want, you may make it safer if you use `(?!\++ )`)
    - `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible